# chrome.alarms.onAlarm throws Uncaught TypeError, cannot read property 'onAlarm' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm writing a Chrome extension, and I keep getting an error message that chrome.alarms is undefined.

My manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "C",
  "description": "whatever",

  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
    },

  "permissions": ["background", "storage", "notifications", "alarms"],

   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "logo.png",
      "default_title": "C",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

In my background.js file:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.alarms.create('arbitrary', {
        when: 1000,
        periodInMinutes: 0.05
    });
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {
   console.log('alarm called');
});
```

In my popup.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({addressInfo: 'text'});
});
```

I have it loaded on my computer as an unpacked extension, so `periodInMinutes` and `when` 1 minute constraints specified by the Chrome API documentation don't apply here.

Comment: Unlikely, but are you using Chrome < 22? [Stable since Chrome 22](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html) is why I ask.

Comment: @trojansdestroy I'm running version  30.0.1599.101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem shortly after posting this. If anyone wants to know, all I had to do was reload the extension from the extensions page in Chrome. I guess changes in the manifest file don't apply unless the extension is reloaded.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was testing with the Chrome Apps & Extensions dev tool, and reloading the extension there didn't work, either. Uninstalling and reinstalling it (after adding alarms to the permissions in the manifest) fixed the problem.

Comment: The comment is more important than the answer. I confirm that adding `alarms` to the permissions and removing / re-adding the extension are both necessary for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the manifests.json file solves the problem.

Comment: Could you clarify your answer?